# Removing a few lines in a table

Tags: tables

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c|lccc|c|}
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Political Party Preference}}\\\toprule
    & & \textbf{Democrat} & \textbf{Republican} & \textbf{Independent} & \textbf{Total}\\\midrule
    \textbf{Gender} & \textbf{Male} & 11 & 7 & 2 & 20\\
    & \textbf{Female} & 7 & 8 & 1 & 16\\\midrule
    & \textbf{Total}  & 18 & 15 & 3 &  36\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

But I'd like to produce the table shown at:

[image: http://www.education.com/study-help/article/inference-two-way-tables/]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi David, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) :) I edited your post to include the images, and made your snippet into a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) by adding the `booktabs` package. I also removed `thanks` and your name- the best way to thank folks is to upvote answers :) and your name appears in the bottom right of your question :) Welcome!

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest you not to use vertical rules at all (the booktabs package documentation has some arguments in favor of this recommendation); if you add vertical rules, they won't interact well with the `booktabs` package (as you've noticed) and trying to make the rules work will spoil the table layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c>{\bfseries}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Political Party Preference}} \\
& & \textbf{Democrat} & \textbf{Republican} & \textbf{Independent} &   
  \textbf{Total} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-5}\cmidrule(l){6-6}
\textbf{Gender} & Male & 11 & 7 & 2 & 20 \\
& Female & 7 & 8 & 1 & 16\\
\midrule
& Total  & 18 & 15 & 3 &  36\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or even like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
Gender & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Political Party Preference}} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& \textbf{Democrat} & \textbf{Republican} & \textbf{Independent} &   
  \textbf{Total} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(l){5-5}
Male & 11 & 7 & 2 & 20 \\
Female & 7 & 8 & 1 & 16\\
\midrule
Total  & 18 & 15 & 3 &  36\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks nice! And I learned quite a bit.

Comment: @user16203 I am glad to hear my answer helped. Please consider accepting it (different from up-voting it) after a sensible wait (perhaps another better answer can appear). In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: Best answer is added by @cv-radhakrishnan, exactly as the OP wanted.

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham I guess that's up to the OP.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina But the *best* answer was added later than your comment. How can one be sure, a better answer is not possible? A discussion here http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2753/is-it-okay-to-ask-the-op-to-accept-the-answer

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham and that's why I said things like "after a sensible wait" and "perhaps another better answer can appear". And again, the final decision is up to the OP.

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham: Accepting an answer is reversible. OP can always change the accepted answer later. (Hence should not be an issue.)

Answer (score 8):

@user16203 You might try this code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tabls,pxfonts}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{c|lccc|c|}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Political Party Preference}} \\\cline{2-6}
                 & & \textsf{Democrat}  & \textsf{Republican} 
                 & \textsf{Independent} & \textsf{Total} \\ \cline{2-6}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Gender}}& \textbf{Male}   & 11 & 7  & 2 & 20 \\
            & \textbf{Female} & 7  & 8  & 1 & 16\\ \cline{2-6}
            & \textbf{Total}  & 18 & 15 & 3 & 36\\ \cline{2-6}
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}

 \end{document}
```

[image: Please see the output]

Comment: Was wondering how to control `\hline` to get the desired output. Great answer, Thank you. By the way, why is `pxfonts` used?

Comment: pxfonts are not necessary at all, I have used to generate non-cmr looking graphic to upload.